# rotate a square with a plane keeping the offset

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to rotate a small square in the same time the background. The rotation is individual. So I can't group both and rotate at once.

I have the rotation angle of the background plane. I don't want to use canvas context, just math!

here is what I tried to do

```
    var radians = Math.abs((Math.PI / 180 ) * angle);
    var cos = Math.cos(radians);
    var sin = Math.sin(radians);
    var newPoint = new Object();

    newPoint.x = cos * (x-cx)-sin * (y-cy) + cx;
    newPoint.y = sin * (x-cx)+cos * (y-cy) + cy;
```

where cx/cy is the pivot. Is the math correct or am I missing something ?

I used javascript, but please make abstraction of js

I have fig.a and I want to rotate both as it is showing up in fig. 2. Fig 3 is an example of what I don't want
[Fig a is what I have, fig 2 is what I need, and fig 3 is what I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH0HU.jpg)

On users request I have created a small demo

```css
#plane {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.3);
}

.wrapper {
position: relative;

}

#square {

position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 20px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- plane it can be a pdf, video, canvas or anything and I get the rotation angle -->
<div id="plane">Lorem ipsum text</div>
<!-- based on the angle of the plane I need to rotate and position this  -->
<div id="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide html and css of the container you are trying to rotate?

Comment: I have update it the post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to this. Consider every thing as individual objects, even the background. The idea is to perform transformation on the coordinate system. Here, is a canvas implementation. [Run]

```js
var box1 = { x : 100, y : 140, width : 100, height : 200, pivotX : 50, pivotY : 50, rotate : 20},
box2 = { x : 200, y : 150, width : 50, height : 150, pivotX : 10, pivotY : 100, rotate : 40}

window.onload = function(){
  let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      width = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
      height = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
     
   render(ctx)
}

function render(ctx){
  draw(ctx, box1)
  draw(ctx, box2)
}

function draw(ctx, box){
  ctx.save()
  ctx.translate(box.x, box.y) // translate the coordinate system
  ctx.rotate(box.rotate * Math.PI / 180)  // rotate the coordinate system
  ctx.fillStyle = "#cccccc"
  ctx.fillRect(-box.pivotX, -box.pivotY, box.width, box.height)
  //draw pivot
  ctx.fillStyle = "coral"
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.arc(0,0,4,0,Math.PI * 2)
  ctx.fill()
  ctx.restore()
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: The box is positioned by just top and right so yes is just x,y. Is there a way to rotate based on pure math ? without using canvas cntx ?